# How to handle FFMPEG module missing probe inside docker?

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, ffmpeg, dockerfile

I am AWARE of how to solve this problem of missing problem module with spleeter on WINDOWS. Here is the solution
https://github.com/deezer/spleeter/issues/101

How can I achieve the same inside my docker container? In my docker file, the FFMPEG is being installed but it is missing the probe module. This is a common problem but one that I don't know how to solve inside of Docker.

I tried doing

```
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
RUN pip uninstall ffmpeg-python
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

in my docker file but didn't work. The thing is, it was all working until last night. Today morning, I am getting this error when I rebuilt my docker image. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is there any help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a hack, this worked for me -

```
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip uninstall -y ffmpeg-python==0.2.0
RUN pip install ffmpeg-python==0.2.0
```